# Handling multiple conditions in kapacitor tick script

Tags: kapacitor

I am monitoring the servers in our local lab environment using the components in tick stack by installing the telegraf agent on each machine which updates the cpu,disk and memory stats to an InfluxDB.I have the tick scripts in the kapacitor which raises the alerts,but my problem here is each server has a different metric value to monitor(like server1 should be alerted on 80% CPU usage and server2 to be alerted on 50% CPU usage) so which means should i be writing multiple scripts for each of the server as it will be difficult to monitor and maintain.Can any one please guide on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create templated tasks with Kapacitor.
https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/working/template_tasks/

But to me it's very restricted, so i wrote an jinja2 template what generates tasks by yaml configuration. I just mention it, if you meet some restrictions in Kapacitor templates.